# GlobalAlloc causes my Delphi app hang?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm want to convert a string value to a global memory handle and vice versa, using the following functions I've just written.

But `StrToGlobalHandle()` causes my testing program hangs. So `GlobalHandleToStr()` is untest-able yet and I'm also wondering if my code is logical or not.

```
function StrToGlobalHandle(const aText: string): HGLOBAL;
var
  ptr: PChar;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if aText <> '' then
  begin
    Result := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, length(aText) + 1);
    if Result <> 0 then
    begin
      ptr := GlobalLock(Result);
      if Assigned(ptr) then
      begin
        StrCopy(ptr, PChar(aText));
        GlobalUnlock(Result);
      end
    end;
  end;
end;

function GlobalHandleToStr(const aHandle: HGLOBAL): string;
var
  ptrSrc: PChar;
begin
  ptrSrc := GlobalLock(aHandle);
  if Assigned(ptrSrc) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(ptrSrc));
    StrCopy(PChar(Result), ptrSrc);
    GlobalUnlock(aHandle);
  end
end;
```

Testing code:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  h: HGLOBAL;
  s: string;
  s2: string;
begin
  s := 'this is a test string';
  h := StrToGlobalHandle(s);
  s2 := GlobalHandleToStr(h);
  ShowMessage(s2);
  GlobalFree(h);
end;
```

BTW, I want to use these two functions as helpers to send string values between programs - send a global handle from process A to process B, and process B get the string using `GlobalHandleToStr()`. 
BTW 2, I know WM_COPY and other IPC methods, those are not suitable in my case.

Comment: GlobalAlloc won't help you for sending strings between programs. The LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc functions do the same in 32bit application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366596(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How do you determine that your program hangs at GlobalAlloc? And if you haven't even gotten to the point of calling GlobalHandleToStr, then it's obviously not the source of your problem, and you should omit it from the question. Keep this question focused on finding the cause of the supposed hang, not on assessing the design of your IPC technique. That's an entirely separate issue.

Comment: You could just use a COM interface to send strings between programs

Comment: @Rob, sorry if I didn't stated it clearly, but I did say "But StrToGlobalHandle() causes my testing program hangs", and see my comment about the accepted answer.

Comment: @Toby, actually in my case, COM is easier, but I'm trying to avoid COM, and I want my app to be more cross-platform ready...

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for the info, I should have known that earlier...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strings in  Delphi 2010 are  unicode, so you are not allocating the proper buffer size.

replace this line

```
Result := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, length(aText) + 1);
```

with this

```
Result := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, (length(aText) + 1)* SizeOf(Char));
```

Comment: Surely that would hang on `StrCopy` not `GlobalAlloc` (assuming it hangs for this reason)?

Comment: Edwin did not say that `GlobalAlloc()` was hanging, he said `StrToGlobalHandle()` was hanging, so it very well could be `StrCopy()` is hanging when it tries to access memory outside of the allocated block, since it is not large enough to hold the entire string.

Comment: RRUZ fixed the problem, thanks! @JamesB, sorry for misleading by the question title - my initial guess was `GlobalAlloc`, but obviously it turned out that it's `StrCopy`.

Answer (score 3):

If your program hangs when you call `GlobalAlloc`, then you probably have **heap corruption** from earlier in your program. That leads to undefined behavior; the function might detect the problem and return an error, it might crash your program, it might silently corrupt yet more of your memory, it might hang, or it might do any number of other things.

That heap corruption *might* come from a previous call to `StrToGlobalHandle` because your `StrCopy` call writes beyond the end of the allocated memory. You're allocating bytes, but the `Length` function returns the number of *characters* in the string. That's only valid when characters are one byte wide, which isn't the case as of Delphi 2009. Multiply by `SizeOf(Char)` to get a byte count:

```
Result := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, SizeOf(Char) * (Length(aText) + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send data between programs using `GlobalAlloc` - it worked only in 16-bit Windows. Use Memory Mapped File instead.

Comment: What does that have to do with the supposed hang of GlobalAlloc?

Comment: Nothing; See BTW at the bottom of the question. The OP should drop his idea completely.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info, I didn't know that... I'll try and see what will happen.